# Can I still import mysql tables if my sql dump includes information_schema database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported everything using phpmyadmin and now I can't import my databases anymore because I get errors on the information_schema.

Is it possible to choose what tables in the dump file to import?

Answer (score 2):

PHPMyAdmin's export just creates SQL file. Delete queries you want to omit and run the import

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

PHPMyAdmin does not support table selection on import.

The easiest way to solve this issue is to export only the necessary tables. But if that is not possible, you can always manually remove the unnecessary tables with a text editor.

Comment: ^this what helped me. But no good editor opened .sql dumps with 40MB+ on Mac. `Coda` hanged, `gedit` also. `Komodo edit` was the only that, while a little laggy, could edit. Anyways, +1 to @Casey